# VBA Read a texts files: permission denied

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder contain texts files . The text is presented as below :

```
NAME   Number   Mail  Date
xx      1       zz    //
```

and I want to write a vba code that read all the text files and search for an information "NAME" to replace it with "name"and then save the modifications . 
I did the code below , but I have an `error 70 permission denied` in `Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile(Fichier, forWriting, True)`  ,

could you help me ?

```
Sub Sample()
     dim fso=createobject("scripting.filesystemObject") 
     dim f
     dim path as string
     dim file_txt as string

      path= "C:\Users\Folder\Fileshere\"
      file_txt= Dir(path & "*.*")

    Do While Len(file_txt) > 0
      'Set objfile = FSO.CreateTextFile(path & file_txt)
      Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile(file_txt, ForReading)
      While Not f.AtEndOfStream
      Namechange = f.ReadAll
      Wend
      Namechange = Replace(Namechange , "NAME", "name")
      Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile(file_txt, forWriting, True)
      f.Write Namechange 

    file_txt=dir()
    loop
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite using a bit more of the `FileSystemObject` functionality rather than using `Dir()` personally, but that's open to your own choice.  The key issue I think you are having is that you have opened the file for reading and then immediately tried to open it for writing while the `TextStream` object is still in memory, and locking the file.  This is why you are getting "Permission denied".  To quote from a [TechNet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198716.aspx):

> Opening Text Files
>
> Working with text files is a three-step process.
>   Before you can do anything else, you must open the text file. This can
>   be done either by opening an existing file or by creating a new text
>   file. (When you create a new file, that file is automatically opened
>   and ready for use.) Either approach returns a reference to the
>   TextStream object. After you have a reference to the TextStream
>   object, you can either read from or write to the file. However, you
>   cannot simultaneously read from and write to the same file. In other
>   words, you cannot open a file, read the contents, and then write
>   additional data to the file, all in the same operation. Instead, you
>   must read the contents, close the file, and then reopen and write the
>   additional data. When you open an existing text file, the file can be
>   opened either for reading or for writing. When you create a new text
>   file, the file is open only for writing, if for no other reason than
>   that there is no content to read. Finally, you should always close a
>   text file. Although this is not required (the file will generally be
>   closed as soon as the script terminates), it is good programming
>   practice.

My code should work for your requirements.  I've removed the While loop from the middle as if you are using `ReadAll` then you don't need to loop over the text.

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemObject")
    Dim file, folder
    Dim path As String
    Dim file_txt As String
    path = "C:\users\folders\fileshere\"
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

    For Each file In folder.Files
        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(file.Path, 1)
        Namechange = file.ReadAll
        file.Close
        Namechange = Replace(Namechange, "NAME", "name")
        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(file.Path, 2, True)
        file.Write Namechange
        file.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

If you have any difficulties or would like further explanation of the above, let me know.

Comment: `Dir` and [`Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) are generally much faster, but I agree if you're using FSO at all, you might as well use it for everything including traversing the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Some minor changes and it worked for me. Please change the path as per your own requirement in following code:

```
Sub change_txt()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemObject")
Dim f
Dim path As String
Dim file_txt As String

path = "D:\Folder\Fileshare\"
file_txt = Dir(path & "*.*")

Do While Len(file_txt) > 0
    'Set objfile = FSO.CreateTextFile(path & file_txt)
    Set f = fso.opentextfile(path & file_txt, 1)

    While Not f.AtEndOfStream
        Namechange = f.ReadAll
    Wend
    Namechange = Replace(Namechange, "NAME", "name")
    Set f = fso.opentextfile(path & file_txt, 2)
    f.Write Namechange

    file_txt = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```